# Pass data on jQuery programmatic click / trigger

Tags: click, jquery

This works great to determine what exactly was clicked but only if it was by one of two instances, user or code.

```
$('#this').on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        var url = this url;  
    } else {
        var url = that url; 
    }
})
```

Is there a way though to pass data to the event object in this format from .trigger() to determine what exactly was clicked? So I could do rerun the orignal click function but pass different variables with something like...

```
$('#this').on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        var url = this url;
    } else if (prev was clicked) {
        var url = that url;
    } else if (next was clicked) {
        var url = theother url;
    }

    switch(url)
})
```

Comment: you mean to detect what exact element is being clicked?

Comment: correct, the question is kinda confusing now that I read it a few times. Trying to run this same click event and just pass different varibles based on what was clicked within what was triggered by the orginal click event. Maybe event.originalEvent.type == 'click' holds the key? Need 3 different options

Comment: Thanks Joke, I've assigned unique ID's to each element which is ran though the switch statement so I could go that route. I think I have to maybe turn the switch into it's own function and call it after I determined where the click came from.